# How do I generate the same random string each time I call a random function in a single iteration of the code?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a Rock, Paper, Scissors game to be played in the command line. At the end of the code, I console.log 3 things: human selection, computer selection (which is randomly generated), and then the outcome of the game e.g. "You win! Rock beats Scissors!"

The problem is that sometimes the outcome line returns the correct outcome based on the human and computer selections, but sometimes it will produce a different outcome statement, even if the 2 selections are identical. e.g. if the selections were human = rock and computer = rock, it might return "It's a tie!" on one go, and then "You lose! Paper beats rock" on another go, even if it's still rock vs rock.

I think the issue is at the 3 console.log statements at the end. First, the human selection is always constant at "Rock", so that's fine. Second, I log the computer selection which is randomly generated. Third, when I log the outcome round which takes the human selection and the random computer selection as  arguments, it's running the random function again and pulling a *different* random selection for the computer. This means that what is logged as the human and computer selections in the first 2 logs will not be congruent with the third log (the outcome) because they're pulling different random strings, which are sometimes the same but sometimes not the same (since they're random).

So I guess my question is: how do I get the random selection to be the same string each time I call it within the code?

Here is my full code:

```
<script>

//human selection

const humanPlay = "Rock";

//randomly select for computer

function computerPlay() {
    computerOptions = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
    return computerOptions[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerOptions.length)];
}

//play a round of human selection vs random computer selection and return a win/loss/tie statement

function playRound(humanPlay, computerPlay) {
    //tie conditions
    if (humanPlay == computerPlay){
        return "It's a tie!"
    //human win conditions
    } else if (
        (humanPlay == "Rock" && computerPlay == "Scissors") ||
        (humanPlay == "Scissors" && computerPlay == "Paper") ||
        (humanPlay == "Paper" && computerPlay == "Rock")
        ) {
        return "You Win!" + ` ${humanPlay}` + " beats" + ` ${computerPlay}` + "!";
    //computer win conditions
    } else {
        return "You Lose!" + ` ${computerPlay}` + " beats" + ` ${humanPlay}` + "!"
    }
}

console.log(humanPlay);
console.log(computerPlay());
console.log(playRound(humanPlay, computerPlay()));

</script>
```

Comment: You need to save the result of calling computerPlay() in a variable, otherwise the program computes a new random number every time

Comment: Ohhh. I did try that but I see I was doing it wrong - I tried storing the function in a variable as I wrote it e.g. `variable = computerPlay(){function here};` etc. and that didn't work. But I see now I should run the function, then store the output in a variable afterwards e.g. `computerPlay(){function here}; let variable = computerPlay()`. Works now, thanks a lot!